# Iterate through text file and add users

Tags: useradd

I have a list of users I want to add as users to my server (userlist.txt).

I want to add them using useradd and include their name as a comment

so... every line of the file contains something like this:

```
vno572,2548,veronica norena,cornerstone group,user,4331,1872,49:46
```

I want to grab "vno572" + "veronia norena" and add the user like this:

```
useradd vno572 -c "veronica norena"
```

I need to iterate through the whole file and add each user in each line.

I have this so far:

```
cat userlist.txt | while read line 
do 
  echo $userid
  userid=’cut -d ‘,’ -f 1 userlist.txt’ 
  echo $name
  name=’cut -d ‘,‘ -f 3 userlist.txt’
  useradd $userid -c “$name”  
done
```

Comment: Might want to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/880221/how-to-add-users-from-csv-by-specific-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1, $3 }' userlist.txt |
while IFS=, read username realname; do
    useradd -c "$realname" "$username" 
done
```

The `awk` above will pick out the first and third column out of the supplied file and create a comma-separated list of username followed by real name.

The comma-separated output from `awk` is read, split on commas, and stored in the shell variables `username` and `realname`, and `useradd` is invoked.

Usually when one creates a user, one may want to add a home directory for them at the same time. Do this by adding `-m` to the invocation of `useradd`. If the users should be part of a particular group or have secondary groups, use `-g` and `-G` with other pieces of info from the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one, not tested yet:

```
cat userlist.txt|awk -F',' '{print $1" "$3}'|while read var1 var2;
do
useradd $var1 -c "$var2"
done
```

Hope it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` only:

```
awk -F, '{ system(sprintf("useradd %s -c \"%s\"", $1, $3)) }' userlist.txt
```

Comment: Use sprintf function to avoid excessive backslash escapes. See my related answer http://askubuntu.com/a/880184/295286